# Scala: given multiple strings, use an if statement to find if given string is in set 1,2,or none

Tags: scala

Given Strings: `"A", "BDS", "DE", "BO", "IID"`
Here is what I have:

```
def givenStrings(code: List[String]) = {
   //val code = List("A", "BDS", "DE", "BO", "IID")
      if (code.contains("A", "BDS"))
         "It is in the first set";
      else if(security_code.contains("DE", "BO", "IID"))
         "It is in the second set";
      else 
         "Not given";
}

givenStrings(List("A")) -> Should result in "It is in the first set"
givenStrings(List("DE")) -> Should result in "It is in the second set"
givenStrings(List("OOOOOO")) -> Should result in "Not given"
```

The error I get is 
`type mismatch; 
found :String("A") 
required: List[String]`

Comment: Hi @YouSun, the error is clear you're passing an `String` to your function, but it requires a `List[String]`, because that is how you declared it here: **def givenStrings(code: List[String])**.

Comment: also code and securitycode are misleading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're checking if your string contains the list, while what you want is the opposite.

I believe this is more close to what you need.

```
object Codes {
  private val codes: Set[String] = Set("A", "BDS")
  private val securityCodes: Set[String] = Set("DE", "BO", "IID")
  def givenString(code: String): Unit = {
    if (codes.contains(code)) {
      println("It is in the first set")
    } else if (securityCodes.contains(code)) {
      println("It is in the second set")
    } else {
      println("Not given")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, however the keyword contain is not a member of Set[String]

Comment: @YouSun my bad, it is `contains`, I edited the answer - my apologies for the confusion. PS: in this case `contains` is not a keyword, just a **method** name.

Answer (score 1):

The method you wrote is expecting a list, but you are passing in a string. So change your method signature to:

```
def givenStrings(code: String) = {
```

and now you'll have a method that expects a string, and won't complain to you when you give it one.

Now, you also don't want to over-write the value of code that is passed in to your function. You should remove that line.

Finally, you can't just start calling the variable `security_code`. So change that back to simply `code`.

Comment: Thanks, I have changed it to def givenStrings(code: String) = {
      if (code.contains("A", "BDS"))
         "It is in the first set";
      else if(code.contains("DE", "BO", "IID"))
         "It is in the second set";
      else 
         "Not given";
}
givenStrings("A") however I get "Not given" when it should be "It is in the first set"